# adding scenes into blender video duplicates soundtrack from original video

Tags: video

When I tried to add text to blender in a very specific font, I tried using the method of creating a text object in a scene and then added the scene to the video. Since I was creating a music video, I needed to copy that first scene and create more. However, all of a sudden, whatever the first scene was on in the song, the song at that part of the first scene ended up being duplicated into that scene and played awkardly for the following copied scenes of text. This got annoying, but I couldn't figure out a way to silence the imported scenes. What should I do?
[image]

Comment: Instead of using scene strips, (which can be quirky) have you tried simply rendering out an alpha layered text image (.png) for each text? Place them as image strips onto your video where each is supposed to show?  Set them to "Alpha Over" in the properties panel. (Highlite each and press N in the VSE)  They can also be scaled and positioned as needed in the VSE.

Comment: No, I have not. Would that require using an external image editor? Plus, I found that the rendering times are very poor for simply rendering text in the scenes. Should I be using blender for this or am I just using it wrong? Cuz It takes about a minute to render each frame with text in it when I use scenes.

Comment: No you don't have to use an external app.  Rendering the 3D window directly onto your video does put Blender to a lot of extra work and you load the rendering time up significantly, whereas rendering text images takes less than a second for each on a good machine when you use OPenGL.  
 Blender's internal render will also do it but will take a little longer.  Once the images are in place in the VSE, rendering out the final mix is way faster than doing it with a scene input Node.  In fact, the text images won't need the compositor at all unless you're doing something extra.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So, how would I go about editing in only 2d in blender? Would I just use the UV editor mode, enter the text in 3d and render only the 2d portion?

Comment: Also, I feel like blender could benefit from having a simple text adder in the video prompt. In fact, it does, but for some reason restricts the text to a really wacky font. Is there a way I can manually change the font in that text editor?

Comment: You appear to be unfamiliar with what I've suggested so I'll place it here as an answer.  If it's no good to you, leave a comment and I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laying text on top of a video strip in the VSE:

The VSE's built in Text tool?  That gave me no joy either so I do it this way...

In Blender's 3D window, press SHIFT-C to center the 3D cursor.

Add text for one of the subtitles and if there's no camera, add one of those also.  Ensure it is pointing straight down by pressing ALT-R.

View through the camera with Numpad-Zero key.

In the 3D window press N to bring up the window's properties and open the "View" tab and tick "lock camera to view".  Close with N again and zoom the camera in and out so you can see all of the text.  (the "Home" key will automatically fit the view to the available space.
(You can alternatively scale the text)

Various fonts aren't hard to setup, but we'll get to that below.

When you get the text looking right, make a save of this Blender setup and use it as a template for future text image creation.

Render what's in the camera viewport and save it as an alpha layered image in .png format.

To do this go to the render properties at right, (ALT-SPACE) open up it's "Output" tab and nominate the folder for the image and set it to the png format.  Make sure to press the RGBA button at extreme right in order to add an alpha layer.

Whilst in the rendering properties, go to the "shading" tab  and set it's 'alpha' setting slot at right, from 'Sky' to 'Transparent'.

Render using OpenGL or with Blender's internal render.  I prefer OpenGL for this job.
Goto upper left of window and click on "Render-->OpenGL Render Animation"

By choice I'd be creating the text images in one Blender file and using another to produce the final mixed movie in the VSE to keep things straight forward and predictable.

Once the text images have been rendered, lay them over the main movie in the VSE where they're supposed to show.

[image]

You'll need to set each text strip as an "Alpha Over" in it's properties panel but read on beforehand.... 
(Highlite the strip & press N)

The image strips can also be faded in and out by keyframing their opacity.

Because you'll most likely have to position and scale the text, add an effects strip for each text image.
Select the text strip, press SHIFT-A and select "Effects strip-->Transform."

When you use Effects strips, it's best to leave the text properties alone and set Location, Scale, and Opacity settings in the Effects-strip properties instead. (at right when you press N)

The movie along with subtitles can now be rendered.  The VSE will render this arrangement up quite rapidly compared to the method you have been using.

[image]

Fonts:

You can use most fonts that Windows does.  Simply goto the C:\Windows\Fonts folder and copy those you like into Blender's Fonts folder.  That's found in -

C:\Blender277\blender-2.77a-windows64\2.77\datafiles\fonts\

Once you've got a selection of fonts -

Select the text properties at right (F icon) and open the Font tab, click on the "Regular" folder, and select from those you've copied across.

Saving Blender in various setup configurations, will retain all your settings and likes, ready to be used at any time.

Colours and/or textures for added text objects can be set up as with any object.

Comment: Thanks! I get it. I blindly followed a youtube tutorial suggesting to import the scene instead of the rendered image of the scene of text. Still seems like a work around, but this will have to do. Thanks so much!

Comment: With your method, I was able to finish the music video. I will say that I found it really time consuming to save ever line of rendered text to another image, especially when I had to go back and fix a spelling error. But, it worked overall.

Comment: Glad you got there @Jake_314  I have a number of Blend files set up specifically for such functions.  Additionally, this same method enables the creation of animated and other effects, not necessarily text, to be overlaid onto existing footage.  Blender is not the one-click-for-special-effects as some commercial packages, but it does provide an incredible range of tweaks and variations.